# Number of solutions of an infinite linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, conformal-field-theory

Let $F_1(z), F_2(z), F_3(z), \cdots$ be an infinite sequence of functions of a continuous variable $z\in \Omega$ with $\Omega$ an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. The functions $F_n(z)$ are holomorphic on $\Omega$ and the sequence $F_n(z)$ decreases exponentially, uniformly in $z$. The values of $F_n(z)$ can be computed numerically to an arbitrary precision.

Consider the linear equation
$$
\forall z\in\Omega, \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty D_n F_n(z) = 0
$$
We assume that the dimension of space of solutions $(D_1,D_2,D_3,\cdots)$ is $M<\infty$. **How do we determine $M$ numerically?**

In practice we have to consider finite truncated systems
$$
\forall i \in \{1,2,3,\cdots, I\},\quad \sum_{n=1}^N D_n F_n(z_i) = 0 
$$
for some choice of $\{z_i\}$. (This choice can be random.) A crude way to obtain the answer is to plot the $N$ singular values of the finite matrix $G^{N} = (F_n(z_i))_{n, i}$. For $N$ large enough we typically see that $M$ singular values are much smaller than the rest. However, this requires rather large values of $N$. Is there a better way?

The motivation for this question comes from two-dimensional conformal field theory. The linear equation is called the crossing symmetry equation, and the functions $F_n(z)$ are conformal blocks. For more details see the preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.01106 .